# OpenCSV: specify no escape character

Tags: escaping, primitive, opencsv

Is there a way to specify "no escape character" in OpenCSV?

I've tried setting the escape character to the empty string, but because the escape character is a primitive char in the CSVParser class (see below), there's no way for the parser to distinguish between "no escape character" and "use NULL as the escape character."

```
    /**
     * This is the character that the CSVParser will treat as the escape character.
     */
    private final char escape;
```

The character delimited file I'm using contains NULL (U+0000) characters.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Five years later and I'm feeling the same pain here. :)